# Signed int to 16 bit hex string in Java

Tags: java, int, hex, short

I use this code

```
short s = (short) Integer.parseInt("3321",16);
```

to convert from `3321` to `13089`

How can I make the inverse and convert from `13089` to `3321` ?

Comment: short s = (short) Integer.parseInt("13089",10); ?

Comment: No, the result is 13089

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer` provides a [method for this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-).

```
String out = Integer.toHexString(13089);
```

`out` will have the value `"3321"`.